# Gtk+ not updating the widgets correctly

Tags: gtk, gtk3, archlinux

I hope I can describe this problem well. I ran `pacman Syu` a couple days ago and the GTK application I'm working on stopped working correctly. I have ran it again after but the problem persists.

Basically, the program is not responding correctly. As an example, I have a button that, when pressed, should print "aqui" to the console and then move the canvas up (as in, navigate up). However the canvas is not updated, and the output is not printed. Only when I close the application, "aqui" is printed as many times as I pressed the button.

The application seems to respond when another window is opened. If I click on a button that opens a different window, the accumulated changes take effect (multiple "aqui" printed, and the canvas moves up as many times as I clicked). When I click on the button that should close the new window, the button disappears, but the window is still there. Example:

[image: The new window, asking for an input]

[image: After clicking OK]

This is the code for the up button:

```
static gboolean moveUp(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventButton *event,
    gpointer user_data)
{
    windowData->moveY(STEP);
    gtk_widget_queue_draw((GtkWidget*) user_data);
    std::cout << "aqui";
    return TRUE;
}
```

the code for the rotate button, that opens the smaller window seen in the pictures:

```
static gboolean rotateWindowWindow(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventButton *event,
    gpointer user_data) {
  GtkBuilder *builder;
  GError *error = NULL;

  builder = gtk_builder_new();

  if (!gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder, "rotateWindow.glade", &error)) {
    g_warning("%s", error->message);
    g_free(error);
  }

  GtkWidget *rotateWindowWindow;

  rotateWindowWindow = GTK_WIDGET( gtk_builder_get_object( builder, "rotateWindowWindow" ) );
  rotationAngle = (GtkEntry*) GTK_WIDGET( gtk_builder_get_object( builder, "rotationAngle" ) );
  GtkWidget* okButton = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "okButton"));

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(okButton), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(rotateW), rotateWindowWindow);

  gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);
  g_object_unref(G_OBJECT(builder));
  gtk_widget_show_all(rotateWindowWindow);
  gtk_main();

  return TRUE;
}
```

the `rotateW` method that is called when clicking the `okButton`:

```
static gboolean rotateW(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventButton *event,
    gpointer user_data)
{
  double angle = atof(gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(rotationAngle)));
  windowData->rotate(angle);

  displayFile->rotateAll(windowData->getAngle(), windowData->getCenter());

  gtk_widget_destroy((GtkWidget*) user_data);
  return TRUE;
}
```

and the `main` method:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    GtkWidget       *viewport, *buttonUp,
     *buttonDown,   *buttonLeft, *buttonRight, *buttonZoomIn,
     *buttonZoomOut, *newLine, *listWindow, *mainBox, *buttonClose,
     *newPolygon, *newPoint, *translateButton, *scaleButton, 
     *rotateButton, *rotateWindowButton;
    GtkDrawingArea  *drawingArea;
    GError          *error = NULL;

    origin.x = 0;
    origin.y = 0;

    viewportData = new Viewport(300.0, 350.0);
    windowData = new Window(300.0, 350.0);
    sh = new SutherlandHodgeman(windowData);
    cs = new CohenSutherland(windowData);
    nc = new NoClipping(windowData);
    clipper = nc;

    displayFile = new DisplayFile(); 

    Polygon* l = new Polygon("line");
    l->addPoint(0, 0);
    l->addPoint(100, 0);
    displayFile->add(l);

    //l = new Polygon("line2");
    //l->addPoint(5, 5);
    //l->addPoint(500, 15);
    //displayFile->add(l);

    /* Init GTK+ */

    gtk_init( &argc, &argv );

    /* Create new GtkBuilder object */
    mainBuilder = gtk_builder_new();

    /* Load UI from file. If error occurs, report it and quit application.
     * Replace "tut.glade" with your saved project. */
    if( ! gtk_builder_add_from_file( mainBuilder, "interface.glade", &error ) )
    {
        g_warning( "%s", error->message );
        g_free( error );
        return 1;
    }

    /* Get main window pointer from UI */
    mainWindow = GTK_WIDGET( gtk_builder_get_object( mainBuilder, "mainWindow" ) );
    viewport = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(mainBuilder, "viewport"));
    drawingArea = GTK_DRAWING_AREA(gtk_builder_get_object(mainBuilder, "drawingArea"));
    listWindow = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(mainBuilder, "listWindow"));
    buttonClose = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(mainBuilder, "buttonClose"));
    mainBox = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(mainBuilder, "mainBox"));
    buttonUp = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(mainBuilder, "buttonUp"));
    buttonLeft = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(mainBuilder, "buttonLeft"));
    buttonRight = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(mainBuilder, "buttonRight"));
    buttonDown = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(mainBuilder, "buttonDown"));
    buttonZoomIn = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(mainBuilder, "zoomIn"));
    buttonZoomOut = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(mainBuilder, "zoomOut"));
    translateButton = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(mainBuilder, "translateButton"));
    scaleButton = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(mainBuilder, "scaleButton"));
    rotateButton = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(mainBuilder, "rotateButton"));
    newPolygon = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(mainBuilder, "newPolygon"));
    newLine = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(mainBuilder, "newLine"));
    newPoint = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(mainBuilder, "newPoint"));
    cohenButton = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(mainBuilder, "cohenButton"));
    sutherlandButton = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(mainBuilder, "hodgemanButton"));
    noClippingButton = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(mainBuilder, "noClipping"));
    rotateWindowButton = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(mainBuilder, "rotateWindow"));

    g_signal_connect(mainWindow, "delete_event", G_CALLBACK(exit_app), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(buttonClose, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(exit_app), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(drawingArea), "draw", G_CALLBACK(on_draw_event), NULL); 
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(buttonUp), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(moveUp), mainWindow);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(buttonDown), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(moveDown), mainWindow);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(buttonLeft), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(moveLeft), mainWindow);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(buttonRight), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(moveRight), mainWindow);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(buttonZoomIn), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(zoomIn), mainWindow);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(buttonZoomOut), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(zoomOut), mainWindow);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(translateButton), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(translateWindow), mainWindow);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(rotateButton), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(rotateWindow), mainWindow);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(scaleButton), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(scaleWindow), mainWindow);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(newLine), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(newLineWindow), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(newPolygon), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(newPolygonWindow), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(newPoint), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(newPointWindow), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(cohenButton), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(changeClipping), mainWindow);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(sutherlandButton), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(changeClipping), mainWindow);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(noClippingButton), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(changeClipping), mainWindow);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(rotateWindowButton), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(rotateWindowWindow), mainWindow);
    /* Connect signals */
    gtk_builder_connect_signals( mainBuilder, NULL );

    /* Destroy builder, since we don't need it anymore */
    //g_object_unref( G_OBJECT( mainBuilder ) );

    /* Show window. All other widgets are automatically shown by GtkBuilder */
    gtk_widget_show_all( mainWindow );

    /* Start main loop */
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

If this is not enough, the full code is on [github](https://github.com/marianatuma/CG). I apologize in advance, the code is a mess.

---

**EDIT**

Adding `std::endl` to the end of the `std::cout` solved the problem of the strings not being printed in real time. Now they are being printed when I press the button, but the rest of the button's funcitonality, that has to do with affecting the interface, still doesn't update until another window opens.

---

**EDIT 2**

[I made a gif showing how it's behaving right now.](https://i.imgur.com/SAKD4zM.gifv)

I tried downgrading gtk from 3.20.6 to 3.16.1, which didn't work. I also tried downgrading every package (by editing `/etc/pacman.conf` and then running `pacman -Syyuu`) to 03/30/2016, also didn't work.

I also tried removing other instances of `gtk main()` with no success.

Just tried adding this code:

```
if(gtk_events_pending())
    gtk_main_iteration();
```

Which force runs the main loop a single time. That also didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Did you check the pacman log?

Comment: @oldtechaa what am I looking for on the logs? There are no errors, at least explicitly

Comment: Look at what's been updated. A coincidental problem on a pacman update looks like a bug in packaging or the upstream software. But we can't find out what the package is without looking at the logs.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to force GTK to refresh its pending operations.

I do it in python this way :

```
while gtk.events_pending():     #   this forces GTK to refresh the screen
    gtk.main_iteration()
```

As you do not mention what language you are using, you'll have to find out how to reproduce this, but it's probably just

```
 while gtk.events_pending():     #   this forces GTK to refresh the screen
    gtk.main_iteration();
```

Comment: I just downvoted your answer based on the fact that from the code OP provided it is clear that he is not using Python while your answer is and that you did not explain why this help OP. (also the comments in the code do not explain the code at all)

Comment: @ B8vrede : I just edited the answer. This is what OP is searching for.

Comment: I think you are right, most issues that are posted here recently have to do with GTK not being able to do its main iterations, in which case this is a valid answer. :)

Comment: I solved a lot of things with this. Now it's up to OP to decide where exactly he wants GTK to perform its refresh.

Comment: Though they did not explicitly specify the language, you could tell from the code samples it was either C or C++.

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time to help me! I tried the code (I'm using c++ with GTK+, so the code is `if(gtk_events_pending()){gtk_main_iteration();}`), but it didn't help...

Comment: Did you placed `if(gtk_events_pending()){gtk_main_iteration();}` at the end of the methods, just before the `return TRUE;` statements ?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is taht you're callin `gtk_main` twice. In your main (which is ok), and in your `rotateWindowWindow` function (whihch is wrong). Doing so will create a new main loop, in which you'll be stuck until you exit.

Just removing that extra call should be enough to fix your issue.

Comment: hey thanks man, I tried it but it didn't work... I added some info to the post, with some things I tried